# mysql RANK() displaying errors

Tags: mysql, rank

I'm trying to run the following mysql query but I seem to be getting some errors, what could be the issue?
MY QUERY:

```
SELECT id ,RANK() OVER(ORDER BY marks) pos FROM results WHERE class='8east'

ERROR MESSAGES:1.An alias was previously found. (near "pos" at position 39)
               2.Unexpected token. (near "pos" at position 39)
```

I've also tried this->

```
 SELECT id ,RANK() OVER(ORDER BY marks) AS pos FROM results WHERE class='8east'
```

but I still get the same error messages

Comment: What version of mysql are you on - rank comes in on version 8 or above. Note your query is syntactically correct which suggest you are not on version 8.

Comment: Yeah , you are right , I just checked  my version and its lower than 8, thanks.

Comment: Then search for mysql rank and you should find alternatives for previous versions.

Comment: Anycase shown error messages are NOT MySQL messages.

Comment: I've found an alternative            SET @i=0;
SELECT id,marks,@i :=@i+1 AS RANK FROM results WHERE class='8W'
ORDER BY  marks  ASC      but if I get two people with the same marks  they end up having different ranks, what can I change in the query to deal with this